# formatting the CSS in a HTML table to have one line per cell

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I'm developing a webpage to server as a quick reference tool in our work, and I'm using Google's Visualization API [Google Visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arrowformatter) to help speed up things. However, I have a column called 'Database',  which have a bunch of databases used by our company:

```
tc2007 tc200711 tc200712 tc200713 tc200714 tc200715 tc200716 tc200717 tc801 tc2008 tc200718 tc20072 tc810 tc200721 tc820 tc83i tc811 tc830 tc90 tc10ms1/tc10ms2 tc91
```

When I do a search, I would like to have each one of those values above being displayed one element per line, does not matter how many there are, or how large is the table cell going to be. Does someone know how to modify the CSS in other that would work? Now the values are put aside each other in the table, so the formatting does not look good.

Answer (score -1):

can't you just set the width of the column?

```
               <td width="50px">....</td>
```

in CSS

```
           .table td
            {
             width: 50px
             }
```

Comment: Did you test the idea? It does not work, because `width` just sets a minimum width as such.

Comment: I didn't try, sorry, did you try inserting <br/> inbetween each result?